# gcloud node - cross-group transaction?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud, gcloud-node

I am using gcloud node and would like to perform a cross-group transaction. Is it possible with gcloud node? I could not find any documentation about this at https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/v0.26.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. gcloud-node uses the Cloud Datastore RPC/REST API. Unlike the Datastore for App Engine APIs, this [API enables cross-group transactions by default](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#Datastore_What_can_be_done_in_a_transaction) so there is no need to enable them explicitly.

Comment: In my code I am getting two entities (from same Kind), and then updating those 2 entities and inserting another 4 entities in another kind under one transaction (which is past the 5 entity limit in a transaction) and I am getting this error: O: Exception executing rpc.
com.google.apphosting.client.serviceapp.RpcException: operating on too many entity groups in a single transaction.
. I looked into the error and saw I needed to use cross-group transactions to by pass this issue which is why I asked the question. If It is enabled by default, why would I be receiving this error?

Comment: Interesting. The limit is actually 25 now, but it sounds like there may be a bug here. Do you mind filing a bug against gcloud-node on the github page? (github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node). If possible can you include a snippet to reproduce and what environment you are using (local machine, Compute Engine, etc). Please /cc me too (@pcostell).